# angular material select - managing large set of options

Tags: angular, css-selectors, angular-material

I use [angular material select form control](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview) to list options. However, the list can easily be 100k elements long. Storing such large list is not a concern. Displaying options via angular select is, since it hangs web browser.

Also I can't select items by name.

Is there any known workaround, better solution or hack to deal with such use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the list can be so big, using a select form is probably not a good idea, especially in terms of user experience. I would probably use an [autocomplete](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/api) component, which gives you the ability to display the list of options or not, depending on how long the list is (you can use the `showPanel` input property to do this).

Comment: thanks. Indeed autocomplete is better choice. I ended up using [ng-select](https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select) Works very good with large set of objects out of the box and supports infix autocomplete. Many additional options too!